# Why is my UDP so slow?

Tags: performance, networking, tcp, udp, network-protocols

I'm using Iperf on two VMs and when using TCP I find the performance is as follows:

> notroot@ubuntu:~$ iperf -s
>   `------------------------------------------------------------`
>   Server listening on TCP port 5001
>   TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
>   `------------------------------------------------------------`
>   [  4] local 192.168.1.29 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.13 port 52478
>   
> [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
>   
> **[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec  2.22 GBytes  1.90 Gbits/sec**

UDP on the other hand is awful:

> notroot@ubuntu:~$ iperf -s -u
>   `------------------------------------------------------------`
>   Server listening on UDP port 5001
>   Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
>   UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
>   `------------------------------------------------------------`
>   [  3] local 192.168.1.29 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.13 port 33775
>   [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
>   **[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.25 MBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec   0.284 ms    0/  893 (0%)**

I was reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300555/udp-data-transmission-slower-than-tcp)

Questions:

1. What do you think of the results?
2. How can I manipulate the datagram size in case it is a fragmentation issue? Though that said I can confirm that the Iperf client is sending 1470 byte datagrams.

Thanks.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

In this case, the problem is that iperf's default speed for UDP is very slow (see the other answers).  But for less extreme speed differences, check this question on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/432101/why-is-udp-slower-than-tcp-on-ubuntu-server).

Following a quote from [pehrs's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/432101/why-is-udp-slower-than-tcp-on-ubuntu-server)

> Each frame goes through several buffers as you send it: The
> application buffer, The Protocol Buffer, The Software interface buffer
> and the Hardware interface buffer. As you start stressing the stack by
> sending high speed data you will fill up these buffers and either
> block or lose data. You also have strategies for timeliness and
> polling that can impact your performance. For example, by using a
> larger buffer and poll less often you can get much better performance
> while sacrificing latency.
>
> TCP is optimized for high speed bulk transfers while UDP is optimized
> for low latency in the Linux kernel. This has an impact on buffer
> sizes and how data is polled and handed over. In addition to this, you
> frequently have offloading to hardware for TCP. I would expect
> considerably better performance for TCP compared to UDP.
>
> Note that sending high speed data over UDP is usually a bad idea,
> unless you implement your own congestion control. TCP protects your
> network from congestion collapses. Use UDP when you have small amounts
> of data or high timeliness requirements.

Comment: This does not explain a **2000x rate** difference. Even an order of magnitude faster for TCP would not be explainable this way.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is not correct. I've performed such test and the performance difference from UDP to TCP exists, but as @xryl669 says, is way smaller.

In a gigabit link I went from 928Mbit/s (TCP) to 812Mbit/s (UDP)

Answer (score 63):

iPerf uses a default of 1Mb/sec for UDP tests. Use the `-b` flag on the iperf client to specify the UDP bandwidth you want to transmit at e.g.

```
iperf -c 10.79.175.219 -u -f m -b 100M
```

Comment: This is the actual reason and should be the correct answer.

Comment: I've tested this and this is the correct answer.

Comment: Indeed. Use `0` as bit-rate for unlimited.

Answer (score 8):

As Nick answered, **iPerf uses a default of 1Mbit/sec for UDP**.

In order to use the same bandwidth as TCP while performing a UDP test, simply provide `-b` flag with the value of `0`.

```
iperf3 --udp -b 0 -f m -c <server ip>
```

form the documentation,

> **-b, --bandwidth #[KMG][/#]**
>   target bandwidth in bits/sec
>
> (0 for
>   unlimited)
>
> (default 1 Mbit/sec for UDP, unlimited for TCP)
>
> (optional slash and packet count for burst mode)

`-f` in the above command provide type of formatting (`m` if for MBits),

> -f, --format    [kmgKMG]  format to report: Kbits, Mbits, KBytes,
>   MBytes

Comment: I am getting `14.4 KBytes` when i use `-b 0`

Comment: Works for me with iperf3. 1 Mbit/s before, 943 Mbit/s after `-b 0` (on a gigabit link).

Comment: Except this answer is for iperf3 only, not iperf 2.